# Justifying last line of a broken paragraph in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working on a two column manuscript that sometimes requires me to place figures. Some figures are placed at the bottom of a page. The paragraphs however don't end there. I have to place the figure in between a figure. Because the figure in the manuscript require special formatting, I have to break the paragraph mid sentence so that the figure formatting is not applied to the paragraph.

However, when I break the paragraph mid-sentence the last line ends left justified. How can I fully justify the last line? An example is below. You can see the last line of the paragraph continue seamlessly after the figure. I know I can do this by a free floating figure but the journal I'm submitting to does not allow that in the Word document. It is the same journal from which I've posted the below photo from.

How do I do this in Word?

[image]

Comment: I may be missing something here but why don't you just put the Fig 2 caption in a text box? The regular text will flow around it normally. Then, if something requires editing, the formatting is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Open Office has a paragraph-level setting that lets you control the spacing behavior of the last line of a justified paragraph, Word doesn't have anything similar. As a workaround, insert a 'soft break' (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) at the end of the last line in the column. That line will be justified and, if you have paragraph marks and other symbols visible (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>) – and you'll need them visible for the next step –, you'll see that the paragraph mark (¶) has been pushed down to the new line. You can then select that paragraph mark, open the **Font** dialog box, and set the font size to **1**. This will basically hide the extra line.

(If the line where you added the soft break isn't justified, go to **File** > **Options**, click **Advanced**, scroll all the way down to **Layout options for**, and clear (uncheck) the **Don't expand character spaces on a line that ends with SHIFT+RETURN** check box.)

Note, however, that the new line is effectively hidden as described here only if the **Line spacing** field in the paragraph settings is set to something other than **Exactly**. If the journal that you're writing for requires exact (fixed) line spacing (e.g., **Exactly** **12 pt**), the new line will take up a line's worth of space (e.g., 12 points) even if you reduce the font size on the paragraph mark.

Answer (score 3):

I beg to differ from the last guy. The last line of a paragraph in MS Word **can be fully justified** (edge to edge) if you click inside the para and type Ctrl-shift-j. (This is Ctrl and the Capital J) This provides behaviour identical to Open Office where you are asked if the last line of the paragraph should be justified.

I do not believe you can use any of the ribbon icons to achieve this. I once saw it in a list of keyboard short cuts and still remembered it years later when I needed it. I think it is an undocumented feature. Maybe it's a secret and I shouldn't have told you!

Comment: Very interesting. I've never, ever come across that shortcut. It does rely as much on letter spacing as word spacing to achieve the justification, though, whereas OpenOffice relies (correctly, in my view) more on word spacing. Still, I stand corrected that Word doesn't have any such functionality. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm late and maybe off topic, but this may be what OP was looking for:
[image: Don't justify manual line breaks]